# What method does the sklearn VotingClassifier fit use?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

The official document does not seems to provide the info.

I am wondering why we can't provide the VotingClassifier the already trained models so we do not need to train again since the VotingClassifier require us to call the fit method before predicting.

Does it just do:

```
for clf in self.clfs:
    clf.fit(X, y)
```

or does it use some more interesting folding method?

Comment: It just does normal checks on the supplied data (to validate that the features are numeric and targets are understood by the supplied estimators). You can look at the code of [`predict()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/ensemble/voting_classifier.py#L201) and adapt to your use case. If not getting satisfying results, please edit the question to add what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what `VotingClassifier.fit` does:

```py
def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
    ...  # Validates the arguments, estimators, etc.

    self.le_ = LabelEncoder()
    self.le_.fit(y)
    self.classes_ = self.le_.classes_
    self.estimators_ = []

    transformed_y = self.le_.transform(y)

    self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(_parallel_fit_estimator)(clone(clf), X, transformed_y,
                sample_weight)
                for _, clf in self.estimators)

    return self
```

... where `_parallel_fit_estimator` is just a wrapper over `estimator.fit` call:

```py
def _parallel_fit_estimator(estimator, X, y, sample_weight):
    if sample_weight is not None:
        estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight)
    else:
        estimator.fit(X, y)
    return estimator
```

As you can see, the method indeed fits the classifiers (in parallel!) and creates the label encoder `self.le_` and `self.estimators_` attributes. The`predict()` or `transform()` methods are built on top of these attributes, that's why calling `fit()` first is necessary.